# Send 200 response back using Azure functions

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, try-catch, shopify

I am using the `shopify API` and developing a REST API using `Azure functions` and `node.js`. I have subscribed to a webhook that sends me a notification every time a order is created. Now I am trying to validate that webhook and send the response back to as soon as possible because if Shopify's API does not receive the response fast, it send the notification again.
Here is my code

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
try {
        // validate request signature
        const crypto = require('crypto')
        const hmac = req.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256')
        const rawBody = req.rawBody
        const secretKey = process.env.SHOPIFY_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE

        const hash = crypto
            .createHmac('sha256', secretKey)
            .update(rawBody, 'utf8', 'hex')
            .digest('base64')       

        if (hash !== hmac) {
            throw "Unable to validate request"
        }
        context.res = {
            body: {
                status:200,
                message:"Success"
            }
        
        };
        context.done();
    } catch (e) {
        context.log.warn(e)
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                message: e,
            }
        };
    }
    //REST OF MY CODE//
}
```

I am getting an error saying
`Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'. Do not use both in your script. Learn more: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097909` even though I am only using `context.done()`.

Comment: Hope this helps  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python) and [MSDOC1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/sharepoint-webhooks-using-azure-functions)